# cvxpy: Possible sign flip for Lagrange Multiplier/dual variable

Tags: cvxpy

I have encountered a very strange problem when using `cvxpy`. Consider the following two problems:

```
x = cvx.Variable(1, "x")
obj = cvx.Minimize(x)
cons = [x==1]
prob = cvx.Problem(obj, cons)
prob.solve()
print(cons[0].dual_value)
```

Output:  -1

```
x = cvx.Variable(1, "x")
obj = cvx.Maximize(x)
cons = [x==1]
prob = cvx.Problem(obj, cons)
prob.solve()
print(cons[0].dual_value)
```

Output: 1

The only difference is that one is a minimization problem and the other is a maximization problem, but the sign of the dual variable is flipped.

Conceptually, this shouldn't happen as in both cases the Lagrangian is L=x + lambda*(x-1), but I cannot find the documentation on how it is defined.

Does anyone have an explanation on why this is happening?

Comment: That sounds natural since maximizing x is usually treated as minimizing (-x). That is all a matter of convention, the Lagrangian is not fixed throughout the universe but there are sign choices in the construction, especially visible for equality constraints.

Comment: I was suspecting the same thing but was trying to verify what exact convention it is using.    One of the authors said on github it was following Boyd & Vandengerghe's book Convex Optimization, but it does not define the Lagrangian for maximization problem. I rely on the interpretation of the Lagrange multipliers and so convention is important.